# Capturing prefixes and suffixes using regex

Tags: regex

I have a bunch of strings containing a repeating pattern, let's call it `ABCD`, that go like so:

```
ABCDABCDABCD
```

and hence can be captured by the regex `(ABCD)+`. But sometimes the string gets truncated on either end. So I can also have, for example,

```
CDABCDABCDABCDA
```

So the way I see it, there are 3 parts: beginning, repeating portion, and ending; where the beginning has to contain any suffix of `ABCD`, and the ending portion may contain any prefix of `ABCD`.

For this simple case, I could devise something complex, like

```
(BCD|CD|D)?(ABCD)+(A|AB|ABC)?
```

but in reality my repeating pattern is much longer than `ABCD` and so it would be very cumbersome to write out all possible prefixes and suffixes of it. Is there a good general solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
^(.*?)(ABCD)*(?=ABCD(.*)$)(?=.*\1\3$)\3.*\3
```

The begining and the end are respectivly captured in groups 1 and 3. The third capture is performed inside a lookahead to be available to describe the end of the pattern.

`(ABCD)*` will match all the repeated ABCD except the last. Since the lookahead contains ABCD too, you can be sure that a last ABCD follows immediatly. But instead of describing this last ABCD with the subpattern `ABCD`, I use the backreference `\3` (that can be: `'', A, AB, ABC`), an undetermined number of characters, and I check the backreference `\1` (that can be: `'', D, CD, BCD`) inside a lookahead to allow overlapping cases (i.e. if `\1` matches `BCD` and `\3` matches `ABC`)

The idea is to match the last ABCD with `\3.*` and to check the group 1  with `(?=.*\1\3$)`

Comment: This almost works, but not quite. Whenever the prefix starts and suffix ends with the same character it seems to fail. For example, it doesn't capture `BCDABCDAB` nor `CDABCDABC`.

Comment: This answer does not satisfy the OP's original requirement that the pattern `"ABCD"` is actually variable length.

Comment: @sawa: It isn't a problem, you can replace all `{0,4}` with `*`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte You didn't do so.

Comment: @sawa: Because it isn't important.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte That was the whole point of the question. If you are going to just hard-code the particular pattern, then the OP already had it. You are miunderstanding the point of the question.

Comment: Oh boy, I see this problem now. And when I replace {0,4} with *, it allows incorrect strings like `AABCD`.

Comment: Actually, the original pattern allows incorrect strings like `AABCD` too!

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron: Add a `$` at the end of the second lookahead.

Comment: Ok... I think it works now. A simpler solution would be preferred but I don't know if one exists! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I have one more question. What if I also want to recognize strings that contain a prefix or a suffix or both? So along with the other strings it recognizes, it would also recognize A, AB, ABC, B, BC, BCD, BCDA, BCDAB, BCDABC, C, CD, CDA, CDAB, CDABC, D, DA, DAB, and DABC? This is so that I can include cases that are going to repeat but haven't done so yet.

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron: One way consist to generate automatically this pattern: `^(?:(?<=D|^)A(?=B|$)|(?<=A|^)B(?=C|$)|(?<=B|^)C(?=D|$)|(?<=C|^)D(?=A|$))++$` But it can be constraignant and the result maybe a little slow.

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron: An other way consists to test if:  `length(string) < 2*length(ABCD)-1`. If true, You only need to check if the string is contained in `ABCDABCD`