# Capturing prefixes or suffixes or both using regex

Tags: regex

Yesterday I asked about [Capturing prefixes and suffixes using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507218/capturing-prefixes-and-suffixes-using-regex). For a given repeating pattern `ABCD`, I wanted a regex that would capture "fully" repeated strings like `ABCD` and `ABCDABCDABCD` as well as "truncated" ones like `ABCDA` and `DABCDABCD`. For this task, [Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte) generously offered the following nice regex:

```
^(.*?)(ABCD)*(?=ABCD(.*)$)(?=.*\1\3$)\3.*\3
```

which indeed matched my specification. But now I want to add the additional caveat that the repeating pattern doesn't need to have occurred yet, so in addition to what this regex captures, the following strings would also be legal:

```
A
AB
ABC
B
BC
BCD
BCDA
BCDAB
BCDABC
C
CD
CDA
CDAB
CDABC
D
DA
DAB
DABC
```

How can I either modify this regex or come up with a new one to also capture these strings?

Please note that I'm looking for a general solution that will work on a repeating pattern of variable length.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I would suggest something like this:

```
^(?:A(?=B|$)|B(?=C|$)|C(?=D|$)|D(?=A|$))+
```

This has 4 parts in the grand scheme of things, which are very similar to each other:

```
^          # Beginning
(?:
  A(?=B|$) # A followed by a B or end of string
|
  B(?=C|$) # B followed by a C or end of string
|
  C(?=D|$) # C followed by a D or end of string
|
  D(?=A|$) # D followed by an A or end of string
)+         # Repeat as many times as necessary
```

Comment: Simply a beauty jerry !

Comment: what tool do you use for the explanation of your regex ?

Comment: @aelor Thanks. And I did it by hand...? (by pressing enter, space, hash, etc)

Comment: Forgot to mention, the above regex was tested [here](http://regex101.com/r/bP3bR1).

Comment: @Jerry, thanks for your help, but unfortunately I don't think this solution will work for me because my ABCD repeating patterns are very long and complex. The solution I seek should not require the pattern string to be decomposed.

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron I don't think I understand. Is there a way for you to give a problem where it is not as simple as the one you have but complex enough to given an idea of how complex your real problem is?

Comment: Sorry if I've posed a bit of an XY problem here. To give full details, I'm particularly interested in any repeating string that can be generated by `(0?Pp1Nn|0?Pp|1?Nn)(2?Tt)?(3?Uu)?`. So it could be something as simple as `Pp` repeating, or as complex as `0Pp1Nn2Tt3Uu` repeating. In both cases, it should accept both complete repeats like `PpPp` as well as incomplete ones like `pPp` and `PpP` and not yet fully repeated ones like `P` and `p`. The original solution worked for full and truncated repeats but not the not-yet-fully repeated ones, and it allowed me to just paste in my pattern.

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron I tried to think about it, but I can't seem to find a regex that would solve your problem, because you have a group and as a group, it's either match the group, or not match it, with no in-betweens of partial matches. :( Unless you can edit what's inside the group.